# Proving that any well behaved function f(x) can be presented as Gauss-Hermite series.

Tags: fourier-series

I've successfully shown that Legendre polynomials are an orthonormal basis for functions.  However, I'm wondering how to proof that all functions f(x) can be written in the form (Gauss-Hermite series):

[image]

where $a$ are constants are $e$ are the Legendre polynomials.

Comment: Please do not repost a question after it is poorly received. Edit the original to bring up the quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that $\psi_n (x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n n!}} \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{\pi}} e^{-\frac12 x^2}e_n(x)$, $n \in \mathbb N$ are all the eigenfunctions of the quantum harmonic oscillator: 
$$ - \frac12 \psi_n ''(x) +\frac12 x^2 \psi_n(x) = E_n\psi_n(x), \qquad E_n=n+\frac12. $$
We know that such functions constitute a basis for $L^2(\mathbb R)$, and your result follows for $f \in L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Um... is there another way to prove this? I haven't learn about this yet.

Comment: I don't expect that to be the case. You might have a look at Stone-Weierstrass https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem (but then you got some work to do) - this is easier (in my mind)